# Diophantine equation in rationals $4 k + m^2=n^2$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I am trying to solve the Diophantine equation

$$4 k + m^2 = n^2$$

in rationals.

This looks very simple, but I stuck with this. 
I have represented this in terms of integers, but again no success:

$$k_2 n_2^2 m_1^2 + 4 k_1 n_2^2 m_2^2= k_2 n_1^2 m_2^2$$

where $k=\frac{k_1}{k_2},m=\frac{m_1}{m_2},n=\frac{n_1}{n_2}$.

EDITED:

I am trying to find such $k$ and $m$ that

$$4k+m^2$$ is square of rational number.

EDITED 2:
The problem I am working on is finding of general solution for this equation.

Comment: Do you want to solve it for $k$, $n$ and $m$? Or is $k$ a parameter?

Comment: I am looking for triples $k,n,m$.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but I thought that when you say "Diophantine equation", the understanding is that you are looking for integer solutions. Is that correct?

Comment: Actually they are equivalent in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that you want is some like a parametrization, you can take $ n = \frac{a + b}{2} $, $ m = \frac{a - b}{2} $. Then
$$
k = \frac{n^2 - m^2}{4} = 
\frac{ \left( \frac{a + b}{2} \right)^2 -\left( \frac{a - b}{2} \right)^2 }{4} = ab / 4
$$
So, all the solutions are given by 
$$
\begin{cases}
k = ab / 4 \\
n = \frac{a + b}{2} \\
m = \frac{a - b}{2}
\end{cases},
\ \ a, b \in \mathbb{Q}
$$

Comment: Many thanks. Just wondering if this gives all the solutions?

Comment: Yes. If you have $ m,n,k $ such that  $  4k + m^2 = n^2 $, then solve the system $ n = \frac{a + b}{2} $, $ m = \frac{a - b}{2} $ for $ a, b $ (it is easy to see that the solution are rationals number too). Then the equality $ 4k + m^2 = n^2 $ implies $ k = ab / 4 $.

Comment: This is overkill, since there is a trivial parametrization of all solutions - given $m,n$ there is exactly one $k$.

Comment: The question is to find such  $k$ and $m$ that the $4k+m^2$ is square. For this we need some parametrization. This is the same complexity task as pythagorean triples or any other 2-order diophantine equation.

Answer (score 3):

There are clearly infinitely many solutions. For every rationals $m$ and $n$ just take $k=\frac{n^2-m^2}4$.

Looking for solutions with fixed $k$ is a bit more interesting, but still easy.

You can write $4k=(m+n)(m-n)$ and solve, for example, the system
$$\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}m+n&=&4\\m-n&=&k\end{array}\right.$$
You can choose for the RHS's any expressions whose product is $4k$.

Comment: Sorry my fault: Corrected the question

Comment: Many thanks, I am just looking for general solution.